# Select entire line in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and I want to highlight the entire line (row) of a clicked cell. 
As an example. If I click a cell from table at position (2,3) and my table has 5 columns I want to highlight cells from (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4).

Can someone explain me how can I achieve that?

Comment: This is the default behaviour. That is when you click on a row it becomes "selected". When you click on another row the previous row is unselected and the new row is selected. Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` where you will find a working example.

Comment: See `javax.swing.ListSelectionModel` in the context of [*User Selections*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

Comment: I did not ask how to select. I did ask how to highlight entire row, not just the clicked cell

Comment: What do you mean "highlight"? If you select a row it is highlighted. You want something in addition?

Comment: That's the problem. Its not highlighted entirely. It's highlighted only the cell I click on.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. Also tell us which L&F you are using.